# How to get this table of `(x-a)*(x-b)`, where `a > b`?

Tags: list-manipulation

I am trying get a table of `(x-a)*(x-b)`, where `a > b`.  I tried

```
Table[{(x - a) (x - b)}, {a, 5}, {b, 5}]
```

If I used,

```
Table[{(x - a) (x - b)}, {a, 5}, {b, 5}, {a > b}]
```

I can not get the result. How can I get the correct result?

Comment: One way is `Flatten@Table[{(x - a) (x - b)}, {b, 5}, {a, b+1, 5}]`

Comment: @ThiesHeidecke Thank you very much.

Comment: @ThiesHeidecke How about `(x-a)*(x-b)*(x-c)`, where `a > b>c` ?

Comment: You can always refer to earlier table variables to define the range start/end of all following variables, so the previous answer should generalize to the a,b,c case: `Flatten@Table[{(x - a) (x - b) (x - c)}, {c, 5}, {b, c+1, 5}, {a, b+1, 5}]`.

Comment: Thank you very much.